# Sum of row and columns as x and y axis

Tags: python, matrix, matplotlib, sum, label

I'm a beginner in using python and encountered a problem I hope you can help me with:

Below you can see an example code I have made for plotting a matrix in which the y-axis is presented on the left and the x-axis on top. What I would like is to have at the x-axis on the bottom beneath every column the sum of that column and for the y-axis on the right for every row the sum of that row. 
This would mean that for the first row I want the number 39 as y-label and for the first column I want 39 as x-label.

I hope someone can help me with this problem

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

conf_arr = [[33,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3], 
            [3,31,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
            [0,4,41,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], 
            [0,1,0,30,0,6,0,0,0,0,1], 
            [0,0,0,0,38,10,0,0,0,0,0], 
            [0,0,0,3,1,39,0,0,0,0,4], 
            [0,2,2,0,4,1,31,0,0,0,2],
            [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,36,0,2,0], 
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,5,37,5,1], 
            [3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,39,0], 
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,38]]

norm_conf = []
for i in conf_arr:
    a = 0
    tmp_arr = []
    a = sum(i, 0)
    for j in i:
        tmp_arr.append(float(j)/float(a))
    norm_conf.append(tmp_arr)

fig = plt.figure()
plt.clf()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_aspect(1)
res = ax.imshow(np.array(norm_conf), cmap=plt.cm.OrRd, 
                interpolation='nearest')

width = len(conf_arr)
height = len(conf_arr[0])

for x in xrange(width):
    for y in xrange(height):
        ax.annotate(str(conf_arr[x][y]), xy=(y, x), 
                    horizontalalignment='center',
                    verticalalignment='center')

ax.xaxis.tick_top()
cb = fig.colorbar(res)
alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
plt.ylabel('True Landform (value explanation in info)')
plt.xticks(range(width), alphabet[:width])
plt.yticks(range(height), alphabet[:height])
plt.savefig('confusion_matrix.png', format='png')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sum row #i using this command:

```
sum(conf_arr[i])
```

Remember, in python counting starts from 0 (and not 1 like Matlab).

To invert the matrix, you can use

```
zip(*conf_arr)
```

And then you may sum row #i (which would be in fact column #i).

Comment: I do understand now how to get the sum of each row, but how do I plot those values in a plot of the confusion matrix??